# PowerShell desktop icon to run elevated other user shell

Tags: powershell, runas

I need an icon to click on the desktop that will launch a PowerShell console, running as another user  prompting for a password, in an elevated shell.

Here is what I have tried:

```
#1
Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential "domain\user" -verb runAs

#2
Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential "domain\user" -NoNewWindow -ArgumentList "Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb runAs"

#3
$username = "domain\user"
$password = 'the real deal password'

$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $username, $securePassword
Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential $credential -verb runAs
```

All of which when I click the icon named something.ps1 brings up a flash of a console with an error  and closes.

I have added pause to try and catch the error but the window will not pause from clicking the icon. But when any of these ran in ISE, there is no error and a console properly comes up in the other users context when I run `whoami`.

I am guessing the problem is in UAC since the commands work in ISE but not off the desktop? Or is a clickable icon for this wishful thinking?

Comment: Wrap it into `try,catch,finally`, put host printing commands in `catch` and pause in `finally`. You'll get your exception. Your pause didn't work because exception kills thread execution before you pause it.

Comment: `psexec.exe` from Sysinternal's suite is usually the best bet when trying to run as other users.

Answer (score 3):

Your script is failing because `-Verb runAs` and `-Credential` won't work together (`-Verb` and `-Credential` are in different parameter sets). You can find similar problems mentioned [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/132e170f-e3e8-4178-9454-e37bfccd39ea/startprocess-verb-runas-credential?forum=winserverpowershell).

You can try something like this, if you want to accomplish this in PowerShell itself but the `UAC` prompt will be shown for this (checked in win 10):

```
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString 'pass@word1' -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential "username", $securePassword
Start-Process powershell -Credential $credential -ArgumentList '-noprofile -command &{ Start-Process powershell -verb runas }'
```

**or** you can use `psexec` with `-h` parameter for elevated access.

Answer (score 1):

Well I did actually get this to work though it is not conventional and without the `try`/`catch` statement it does not work for some reason. Also I had to create a shortcut pointing to the `ps1` file.

`script.ps1`:

```
try{
    Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential "domain\user" -ArgumentList “Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb runAs”
} Catch {
    Write-host "Hello"
}
```

And the Shortcut points to `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command "& pathToPs1\script.ps1"` (start in: `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0`)

With these two coupled everything worked and `-Credential` and `-Verb` do work together, that was not issue - try it in ISE - no errors. It seems to be a break in `UAC` and clicking a link from the desktop, though this is speculative just an educated guess on how the resolution is working.

It's not pretty but hope this helps someone else.

Credit for my answer was a combination of [this link](https://www.ucunleashed.com/2941) and [this link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/benshy/2012/06/04/using-a-powershell-script-to-run-as-a-different-user-elevate-the-process/) and a comment to `try` and `catch` the error, thanks to you as well for suggesting the `try`/`catch` statement.